# For each URL in ColA, loop through extracted data. Stuck on UrLFetchApp for multiple URLs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The gist: I'm able to successfully retrieve data using the [original script](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WZmdq3mKo0EygmdCtWT5dMZYGKb28H3IjpFvnAH2SeQ/edit?usp=sharing) for a single URL. Now I need to modify it to add a for each loop to repeat the script for each url in ColA of [my gsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cDw0gJsOqWBazEakacAGtrjisqQJtAbERNv8y9Ifvpk/edit?usp=sharing). After 2 days of trying things I think I'm on to something here, but I know that this line `const str =UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls).getContentText();` is wrong. It worked when I had a const for a single url, and I don't know how to change it (or where to put it) to say: fetch and get content for each of the URLS in the range. I'm learning javascript as I go, so still very much a newbie. Any help is much appreciated.

And yes, I've already been warned about not using Regex, but this works and I need it for Tuesday. I'll rewrite without Regex later.

```
function LoopURLs() {
Loop_clearRecords();
 let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("UserDiary");
 let urlRange = sheet.getRange('A3:A15');
 let urls = urlRange.getValues();
 const str = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls).getContentText();
  const mainRegex = /<td class="td-film-details">([\s\S]*?)>Edit this entry\<\/a>/gi;
  const results = str.match(mainRegex);
  const filmIDRegex = /data-film-id="([0-9]*?)"/i;
  const filmTitleRegex = /data-film-name="([\s\S]*?)"/i;

 urls.forEach(function(row){
   Logger.log('For each loop: ' + row);
   for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    const filmIDResults = (results[i].match(filmIDRegex) || ['','']);
    const filmID1 = filmIDResults[0]; 
    const filmID = filmIDResults[1];
    Logger.log('filmIDcode: ' + filmID1);    
    Logger.log('filmID: ' + filmID);
    const filmTitleResults = (results[i].match(filmTitleRegex) || ['','']);
    const filmTitle1 = filmTitleResults[0]; 
    const filmTitle = filmTitleResults[1];
    Logger.log('titlecode: ' + filmTitle1);  
    Logger.log('title: ' + filmTitle);
 };
})

Loop_addRecord(filmTitle, filmID );
  }

function Loop_clearRecords()
{
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tableSheet = ss.getSheetByName("UserDiary");
 // select range to clear
  tableSheet.getRange("C3:Z100").clear();
}
function Loop_addRecord(filmTitle, filmID) {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tableSheet = ss.getSheetByName("UserDiary");
  var currentRow = tableSheet.getLastRow();
  var nextRow = currentRow + 1;
  tableSheet.getRange(nextRow,4).setValue(filmID);
  tableSheet.getRange(nextRow,5).setValue(filmTitle);
  
}
```

Comment: In your script, it seems that 2 values of `filmTitle, filmID` for each URL are put to the Spreadsheet. But, when I saw `This is the data from the url in A3--I'd like the data for each url to display under this thereby creating one large list.` of your sample Spreadsheet, 12 values are shown. But in your question, this is not mentioned. So I cannot understand your question. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: Tanaike, the original script has one url hardcoded in it, and it gets filmTitle and filmID for that url.  But I have multiple URLS in cells A3-A13, and I would like the script to run for each of those urls; so for url#1 it runs and gets FilmTitle, FilmID, outputs, then it gets URL#2, gets FilmTItle, FilmID, outputs below, and it repeats for all the urls in Col A. Also, I truncated the script displayed here to only get two values (FilmTItle and FilmID) just to make it simpler, as I can add the other values I'm looking for later once I know how to loop the 'for each url', do this...

Comment: Tanaike, one of the reasons I simplified the script here is because I thought it was good form; I've seen many people complain to posters that their code is way too long and that they should just ask for the essentials.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your following replys,

> the original script has one url hardcoded in it, and it gets filmTitle and filmID for that url. But I have multiple URLS in cells A3-A13, and I would like the script to run for each of those urls; so for url#1 it runs and gets FilmTitle, FilmID, outputs, then it gets URL#2, gets FilmTItle, FilmID, outputs below, and it repeats for all the urls in Col A. Also, I truncated the script displayed here to only get two values (FilmTItle and FilmID) just to make it simpler, as I can add the other values I'm looking for later once I know how to loop the 'for each url', do this...

> one of the reasons I simplified the script here is because I thought it was good form; I've seen many people complain to posters that their code is way too long and that they should just ask for the essentials.

I understood your goal of this question is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the URLs from the cells "A3:A11". And, you want to retrieve 2 values of `filmTitle, filmID` from each URL, and put the retrieved values to "C3" in the sheet.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function LoopURLs() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("UserDiary");
  sheet.getRange("C3:Z100").clear();
  let urlRange = sheet.getRange('A3:A13');
  let urls = urlRange.getValues().map(([a]) => ({url: a, muteHttpExceptions: true}));
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(urls);
  const values = res.flatMap(e => {
    if (e.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      const str = e.getContentText();
      const mainRegex = /<td class="td-film-details">([\s\S]*?)>Edit this entry\<\/a>/gi;
      const results = str.match(mainRegex);
      const filmIDRegex = /data-film-id="([0-9]*?)"/i;
      const filmTitleRegex = /data-film-name="([\s\S]*?)"/i;
      const temp = [];
      if (results && results.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          const filmIDResults = (results[i].match(filmIDRegex) || ['', '']);
          const filmID = filmIDResults[1];
          const filmTitleResults = (results[i].match(filmTitleRegex) || ['', '']);
          const filmTitle = filmTitleResults[1];
          temp.push([filmID, filmTitle]);
        }
        return temp;
      }
    }
    return [Array(2).fill("")];
  });
  sheet.getRange(3, 3, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- In this modification, the URLs are requested using the method of fetchAll. And, the values are retrieved from each response and put the values to the sheet. In this case, the values of `filmTitle, filmID` are put from the cell "C3".

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that the values of `filmTitle, filmID` can be retrieved from your URLs. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [fetchAll(requests)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests)

Comment: Tanaike, Thank you. Is it possible that I'm only getting the first result for each url?  I get 8 rows of results instead of hundreds. Each url points to a page that includes about 30 diary entries.  The "mainRegex" gets the large table section of the url page that holds all info I need for my values (FilmID, FilmTitle etc) and that section is read about 30 times to extract the values for each film mentioned in the url. I think that's what's missing here; the script isn't reading through the mainRegex results for all items (30 different films) in each URL. I don't know if I'm explaining it well

Comment: @lise Thank you for replying. From your replying of `I get 8 rows of results instead of hundreds. Each url points to a page that includes about 30 diary entries.`, when I saw your sample Spreadsheet, the URL is put in the cells "A3:A11". So I used that range. If you want to expand it, please modify `A3:A11` of `let urlRange = sheet.getRange('A3:A11');` to other and test it again. This sample script is for your sample Spreadsheet. Please be careful about this. If I misunderstood your reply, I apologize.

Comment: @lise By the way, in your sample Spreadsheet, your explanation documents are inserted into the rows. So I didn't use `getLastRow()` and I directly used a1Notation as the range.

Comment: See if this is clearer.  From the URL in A3 I should get this:
filmID, filmTitle
32348 Close-up
29289 Gertrud
18768 Earth
and about 40 more entries
from the URL in A4 I should get this:
21418 Eastern Plays
370364 November
650606  Quo vais, Aida?
and about 20-30 more
and so on for each url.  It's not the getting of the URLs that is at issue; you fixed that (thank you very much!). It's what is being done with the urls that isn't the same as my original script, even if I were to change my original to JUST get FilmID and FilmTItle.

Comment: @lise Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. In my answer, I used your provided sample Spreadsheet. If your actual Spreadsheet is different from your sample Spreadsheet, unfortunately, I cannot understand your actual Spreadsheet. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: @lise Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your reply. So, for example, in order to correctly understand your reply, can you update your provided sample Spreadsheet? At that time, can you include the sample output situation you expect? By this, I would like to confirm your situation.

Comment: Tanaike, you are being extremely generous with your time. Thank you!  I have modified my original script to just get FilmID and FilmTitle.  It is here:  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Kh0SLYirK5JXh9pAQYZHZE7hG665toZ7zkn3HWBJTEQ/edit?usp=sharing  I have also updated my spreadsheet to display expected results, but also to explain what data I am getting from each url and how I am extracting what I need. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cDw0gJsOqWBazEakacAGtrjisqQJtAbERNv8y9Ifvpk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @lise Thank you for replying. From your replying, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I still misunderstood your question, I apologize again.

Comment: I ran my original script and the results are on "UserDiary2" sheet.
I ran the original script you created and the results are in "User Diary" sheet.
I tried running your latest update but there is an error on line 7
"Exception: Invalid argument: http:// line 7"

Comment: @lise Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I cannot find "UserDiary2" in your sample Spreadsheet. Where can I find it? In your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including my proposed script for correctly replicating your current issue? Because when I used your provided Spreadsheet, no error occurs. I deeply apologize that my test using your sample Spreadsheet doesn't occur the error.

Comment: @lise Now, I noticed that your provided sample Spreadsheet had been changed. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I found my proposed script. When I saw the sheet "test" using my proposed script, the URLs are put to the cells "A3:A11". But my proposed script uses your 1st provided sample Spreadsheet. In that case, the URLs are put to the cells "A3:A13". So I used it. When you use your "test" sheet, please modify "A3:A13" to "A3:A11". By this, the error can be removed. I deeply apologize that I cannot notice that your test sheet uses the cells "A3:A11".

Comment: @lise Or, if you want to use "A3:A13" as the range, how about modifying from `let urls = urlRange.getValues().map(([a]) => ({url: a, muteHttpExceptions: true}));` to `let urls = urlRange.getValues().flatMap(([a]) => (a ? [{ url: a, muteHttpExceptions: true }] : []));`? By this, the empty cells can be ignored.

Comment: Perfect! I added all of the other values that I needed to get to your script and it worked perfectly. Thank you SO much for your time and patience. I appreciate it very much.

Comment: @lise Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.